# Rust で struct Hoge<'a> を 引数 &Hoge として受け取るジェネリックトレイト trait Item<T> を定義したい。

Tags: rust

以下のプログラムのコンパイルを通すジェネリックトレイトを定義したいのですが、どのように記述すればよろしいのでしょうか。

`impl Item<Hoge<'a>>`としたときに、`fn print(&self, h: &Hoge)`となるようなトレイトが記述できれば解決できると思うのですが、そのような記述方法はあるのでしょうか。

```rust
struct Hoge<'a> {
    s: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> Hoge<'a> {
    fn new(s: &'a String) -> Self {
        Self { s }
    }
}

/*
ジェネリックスを使わなければ
trait Item {
    fn print(&self, _h: &Hoge);
}
*/
trait Item<T> {
    fn print(&self, _h: &T) {}
}

struct Item01 {}

impl Item<Hoge<'_>> for Item01 {
    fn print(&self, h: &Hoge) {
        println!("Item01: {}", h.s);
    }
}

struct Test01 {
    item: Box<Item01>,
}

impl Test01 {
    fn new(item: Box<Item01>) -> Self {
        Self { item }
    }
    fn print(&self, h: &Hoge) {
        self.item.print(h);
    }
}

struct Test02<'a> {
    // Item<Hoge> とするとライフタイム指定子がないと怒られる。
    item: Box<dyn Item<Hoge<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Test02<'a> {
    fn new(item: Box<dyn Item<Hoge<'a>>>) -> Self {
        Self { item }
    }
    // &Hoge としたいが self.item.print(h) が &Hoge<'a> を要求する。
    // &Hoge<'a> を要求すると言うより、'a が Test02 より長いライフタイムを要求する。
    fn print(&self, h: &Hoge<'a>) {
        self.item.print(h);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t01 = Test01::new(Box::new(Item01 {}));
    // ここより上に let str = ... とすればよいが、
    // 諸事情により let t02 = ... より下でないと定義できないとする。
    // fn print(&self, h: &Hoge) なら let t02 = ... より下に定義しても問題ないはず。
    let t02 = Test02::new(Box::new(Item01 {}));

    let str = "hoge hoge".to_string();

    let hoge = Hoge::new(&str);
    t01.print(&hoge);
    t02.print(&hoge); // こいつをコメントアウトするとコンパイルは通る
}
```

Comment: おそらくですが、t01.print がエラーにならなくて、t02.print がエラーになる原因は、
t01.print の hoge は、print関数開始から終了までより長いライフタイムしか要求しな
いけど、t02.print の hoge は、t02 より長いライフタイムを要求しているからです。

これは、t02.print が self.item.print を呼んでいるからで、
「item: Box<dyn Item<Hoge<'a>>>」の「'a」が、Test02 のライフタイムと結びついる
からだと思われます。

t02.item.print を呼ぶには、hoge が t02.item より長生きじゃないといけない理由が
あるとすると、Rust は正しいエラーを吐いていることになります。

そうすると、ここの質問は根本的に間違っていることになりますね^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

他のプログラムのライフタイムのバグを解決しようとしていたら、しれっとコンパイラが答えを教えてくれましたw
Test02 を以下のように定義すれば、解決できます。
確認したコンパイラのバージョンは、「rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)」になります。

```
struct Test02 {
    item: Box<dyn for<'a> Item<Hoge<'a>>>,
}

impl Test02 {
    fn new(item: Box<dyn for<'a> Item<Hoge<'a>>>) -> Self {
        Self { item }
    }
    fn print(&self, h: &Hoge) {
        self.item.print(h);
    }
}
```

今どきのコンパイラって優秀ですね!